# How to access file on windows pc connected to my android hotspot from that Android device?

Tags: file-sharing

I created hotspot on my android device then I connected my windows pc to that hotspot. I have file sharing enabled on my windows pc. But I am unable to access my files from that android device.

Answer (score 0):

If file sharing is enabled and the connection isn't being blocked by something, maybe try using something that supports file transfers without using filesharing. I know Teamviewer has support for this. There are also other apps as well I believe.
I guess I'm confused about why this would be your best option to transfer the files though, you could also simply use a charging cable to transfer the files locally. Much faster and simpler.